# How to get "onclick" content to show next to dynamically created content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have a dynamically created list that displays radio buttons next to it. When the radio button is changed I want a dropdown list to appear next to the dynamically created list and radio button that was changed. Basically if I change the button to yes (visible), I want a dropdown list to appear next to it... so depending on how many items are in my list and depending on which ones are set to yes, would be the amount of drop down lists that appear to set the positions (with 8 of the same fixed options in each dynamically created dropdown list).

All I have come up with so far is to create an `onchange` event in jQuery and "unhide"  a pre-made dropdown list - the code works fine but it isn't what is needed. I'll post the code and a picture below:

```
//K's function:
        function get_all_pages() {
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT * 
                FROM pages ";
        $query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
        $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
        $page_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($page_set);
        return $page_set;
    }
//K's function:
function list_all_pages(){
$output = "<ul>";
$page_set = get_all_pages();
while ($page = mysql_fetch_array($page_set)) {
$output .= "<li><a href=\"add_feature.php?page=" . urlencode($page["id"]) . "\">{$page["menu_name"]}</a></li>";
$output .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=\"radio\" class=\"unchecked\" onclick=\"uncheck()\" name=\"visible_{$page["id"]} \" value=\"0\" checked=\"checked\" /> No <input type=\"radio\" class=\"checked\" onclick=\"check()\" name=\"visible_{$page["id"]} \"value=\"1\" /> Yes";
    }
$output .= "</ul>";
return $output;
}   
---------- jquery
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
//alert("document ready");
   $('#position').hide();


 });

$('.checked').change(function() {
     $('#position').show();
});
$('.unchecked').change(function() {
     $('#position').hide();
});
</script>

--------- html (not what is wanted but the only thing I've got going right now....

<form>
<?php echo list_all_pages(); ?>

<div id="position">

<select name="position">
var count;
for (count=1; count <= 8; count++) {
<option value='count'>count</option>;
        }
</select>

</div>

</form>
```

[image]

[image]

New information as of August 27th:
It is semi-working thanks to redrazor11's help in jfiddle... the JavaScript `onchange` in the PHP loop is working but only for the first `<li>`... in fact when I click on the other `<li>` radio buttons the dropdown menu sometimes appears under the first `<li>` again... code and new pictures are posted below:

```
    //K's function:
    function list_all_pages(){
    $output = "<ul>";
    $page_set = get_all_pages();
    while ($page = mysql_fetch_array($page_set)) {
    $output .= "<li><a href=\"add_feature.php?page=" . urlencode($page["id"]) . "\">{$page["menu_name"]}</a></li>";
    
    
    
    $output .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input onchange=\"javascript:document.getElementById(1).style.display = 'block';\" type=\"radio\" name=\"visible_{$page["id"]} \" value=\"0\" checked=\"checked\" /> No <input onchange=\"javascript:document.getElementById(1).style.display = 'none';\" type=\"radio\" name=\"visible_{$page["id"]} \"value=\"1\" /> Yes";
    
    $output .= "<div id='1' style='display: none'><select name='position'><option value='count'>1</option><option value='count'>2</option><option value='count'>3</option></select></div>";
    
    
    
        }
    $output .= "</ul>";
    return $output;
    }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Sept 2nd edits:
I tried the $counter as the ID and then tried using the `$page[id]` and both returned results that worked in terms of getting the div to show up in each li... but there seems to be a problem with the `onclick` JavaScript working correctly... I'm going to post the link if redrazor11 or someone could take a look and maybe figure out this bizarre behavior that is happening on the onclick? link:

http://www.firetreegraphics.com/widget_corp-final/add_feature.php

Here is the recent code changed:

```
//K's function:
function list_all_pages(){
$output = "<ul>";
//$output .= $counter = 0;
$page_set = get_all_pages();
while ($page = mysql_fetch_array($page_set)) {
$output .= "<li><a href=\"add_feature.php?page=" . urlencode($page["id"]) . "\">{$page["menu_name"]}</a></li>";

$output .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id=\"$page[id]\" style='display: none'><select name='position'><option value='count'>1</option><option value='count'>2</option><option value='count'>3</option></select></div>";

$output .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input onchange=\"javascript:document.getElementById('$page[id]').style.display = 'block';\" type=\"radio\" name=\"visible_{$page["id"]} \" value=\"0\" checked=\"checked\" /> No <input onchange=\"javascript:document.getElementById('$page[id]').style.display = 'none';\" type=\"radio\" name=\"visible_{$page["id"]} \"value=\"1\" /> Yes";

//$output .= $counter = $counter+1;

    }
$output .= "</ul>";
return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle I found on an earlier stack exchange post.

The idea is to hide the div with the selection box until you're ready for it to be displayed/populated. You can have have different id'd divs available depending on what was selected. In this example, it's a drop-down that causes the content to appear, but it's a similar idea for radio buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/cpradio/YvN4Q/

Comment: how can i use this idea to make multiple copies of the same dropdown list... depending on what is in my database will be what the list is and depending on which items in the list have their radio buttons set to yes (visible) would be how many dropdown lists I would want to appear (well, I'm going to put a limit of 8, but you get the idea)?

Comment: If you have a loop that creates the radio buttons from the database, just include the hidden div with selector inside that loop. Then each radio button options can have a hidden selector to the right of it, for instance. And when you pick yes, the selector appears to the right.

Comment: I sort of understand but I can't wrap my mind around how exactly it would work

Comment: View this updated fiddle. It's a quick and rough adaptation on the previous one I found, but if it does what I think you're describing you can trim it down to fit your function.

You can put the radio button creation and drop-down creation inside the loop instead of creating them manually as I did in this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/YvN4Q/3/

Comment: @redrazor11.. I tried what you were saying in fiddle.net in the loop and posted results above... what do you think?

Comment: I don't see were you posted results above.

Comment: sorry I posted incorrectly before. I made the edit in the original post this time. I am really excited because the onchange javascript that you suggested worked really well... it seems really close to doing what I want it to do... any suggestions for the problem described above in getting it to appear for each <li> individually?

Comment: From what I can see here, you are modifying element by ID(1)... and if your loop goes 3 times, you will have 3 elements with id="1".

Instead, you should assign id based on loop counter. 

(Ex. $counter = 0; loop(){...getElementByID(".$counter.")... $counter=$counter+1; }

Etc.)

Comment: I posted new results above... sorry this is taking so long to figure out but I really appreciate the help and want to become a better programmer...

Comment: got it!! I changed the onchange to onclick and that did it.. thanks so much for your help!!!